# How to remove msdos parition table label completely on Rocky Linux 8.7

Tags: linux, fdisk, rocky-linux

How to remove msdos partitions on Rocky Linux 8.7, while the command `fdisk -l` provides no partition table label, the command `partprobe` shows msdos label, which I want to remove

```
# fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

# partprobe -s /dev/nvme0n1
/dev/nvme0n1: msdos partitions
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? there is nothing wrong with msdos partition table on a disk of this size.

Comment: If this is not a boot disk and there is no data (or all data was backed up somewhere else), just create another partition table over it. Or `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=512 count=1` will zero first sector which contains MBR partition table and therefore it will be removed with nothing to replace it. Yet unclear why would you want to do that.